# Can't create image from tar.gz file in bucket

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a custom image using **Console** or **gcloud**, i.e. (***Note:*** URLs are masked with *[naURL]* to get around URL posting limitation.):

> $ gcloud compute images create debian-9-1-v20170810-1 --source-uri=https:[naURL]//storage.googleapis.com/[my bucket]/compressed-image.tar.gz

The command runs for about half an hour (i.e. 1800s) and then gives the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.create) Could not fetch resource:
>    - Did not create the following resources within 1800s: https:[naURL]//www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/spherical-proxy-175708/global/images/debian-9-1-v20170810-1. These operations may still be underway remotely and may still succeed; use gcloud list and describe commands or https:[naURL]//console.developers.google.com/ to check resource state

The corresponding REST record accessible via **Console>Compute Engine>Operations** for the item reads:

```
{
  "kind": "compute#operation",
  "id": "5371669110648613089",
  "name": "operation-1502320142020-5565a2a676da1-06d76920-4c86568d",
  "operationType": "insert",
  "targetLink": "https:[naURL]//www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/spherical-proxy-175708/global/images/debian-9-1-v20170810-1",
  "targetId": "3098231522309056737",
  "status": "DONE",
  "user": "andree.leidenfrost@gmail.com",
  "progress": 100,
  "insertTime": "2017-08-09T16:09:02.501-07:00",
  "startTime": "2017-08-09T16:09:03.136-07:00",
  "endTime": "2017-08-09T16:59:29.128-07:00",
  "error": { 
             "errors": [
               {
                 "code": "INTERNAL_ERROR",
                 "message": "Code: '8625676013601614622'"
               }
             ]
           },
  "httpErrorStatusCode": 503,
  "httpErrorMessage": "SERVICE UNAVAILABLE",
  "selfLink": "https:[naURL]//www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/spherical-proxy-175708/global/operations/operation-1502320142020-5565a2a676da1-06d76920-4c86568d"
}
```

Because the HTTP error is 503 "SERVICE UNAVAILABLE" I've tried a few times over the last couple of days but the problem persists.

I'm trying to follow the instructions in document [Importing Boot Disk Images to Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image).

Any help or hints how to debug further would be greatly appreciated!